# HTML tags in variable's printing by echo

Tags: php, mysql, html

**Hello!**

Like in title. 
There is code example.

```
<p><?php echo $post['content']; ?></p>
```

Result is:

> Nulla eu aliquet sapien. Sed in sagittis sem. Maecenas mattis, eros pretium fermentum accumsan, felis metus sollicitudin lacus, sit amet ultrices elit nibh eget mauris. Pellentesque vehicula, enim sit amet interdum porta, ligula massa aliquet ipsum, eu ullamcorper felis mi eget diam. Sed sollicitudin augue quis convallis efficitur. Integer malesuada vel orci sit amet mollis. Maecenas quis pretium odio. Nullam eu dui elementum dolor posuere condimentum at non sem.   <br/>Donec consequat ante suscipit est efficitur, a accumsan est rhoncus. Integer pulvinar eget tellus a aliquet. Mauris ultrices metus at risus ultricies malesuada. Praesent scelerisque finibus metus eu elementum. Nam eros nunc, pulvinar vel tincidunt eget, pretium id libero. Cras hendrerit ex quis dignissim pretium. Duis ipsum urna, interdum sit amet turpis eu, condimentum dictum ante.    <b>Morbi laoreet id turpis in elementum. Nunc libero magna, imperdiet convallis scelerisque quis, auctor et nisi. Curabitur diam turpis, rhoncus in facilisis a, gravida i</b>n tortor. Suspendisse vitae nunc tellus. Maecenas fermentum, mauris vel dapibus viverra, tortor dui aliquet massa, eget feugiat erat nulla ut erat. Quisque fermentum nisi vitae nisl tristique, ac euismod dolor interdum. Donec id efficitur orci. Nullam accumsan convallis congue. Ut vestibulum accumsan ullamcorper. Curabitur congue sem imperdiet velit facilisis, eget lacinia metus ultricies. Donec dui felis, dictum nec neque vel, volutpat auctor dolor.

What's problem?
Tags don't work.

Can someone help me, please?

P.S. It must be printing by echo.

Comment: Tags probably html encoded for less than and greater then symbols like &lt; and &gt; which means you need to call decode function.. can you please provide html source generated by the echo..

Comment: please do `var_dump($post['content']);` and post the results in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to decode html tags

```
html_entity_decode($post['content'])
```

According to PHP Manual:

**html_entity_decode** — Convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters

Comment: @Xemon: great dont forgot to mark as accepted by click on left side tick, this will help to others.